# Retrieving rounded off value from the database

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've been working around with this scenario. In the database I have the data below.

**Item**

- length : 1
- unit of measurement : cm

I would like to know how to query that data using the condition below.

```
length = 0.39 (inch)
```

I came up with 0.39 due to the conversion of cm - inch.

thanks,

Comment: 0.39 inches sounds like the right result. What exact is the problem?

Comment: the condition is : `length` = `0.39`. Unfortunately, no record could be retrieved because `1` != `0.39`

Comment: What condition? You'd have to share some code here, as you're currently left us guessing what the application is supposed to do, and why it isn't working

Comment: thanks @Mureinik , the problem is if i convert 0.39 cm back to inch the result would be 0.9906 inch. and that 0.9906 inch is what i am going to use to query the item which length = 1.

moreover, is there a way in java where i could get the previous result before `ceil` or `rounding off number` ?

Comment: look at lang.math in [java api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), you will find methods `ceil`, `round` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my perception about your question is correct or not this is what i understood from your question.
consider the query for below example

```
MEASUREMENTS(Table)
ID LENGTH UNITOFMEASURE
111 1     CM
123 2     CM
145 5     CM
```

you want to query like select count(*) from MEASUREMENTS where length=0.39(you are planning to pass in inches)

**There is a precision loss  1cm=0.393701 inch
not 0.39.**

Comment: yup that's it.. 0.39 , sometimes we need to query it by 0.40 which is from ceil.

how do we deal with precision loss anyway?